# TypeScript for web without module loader?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, module, es6-module-loader

This is a very confusing topic for me at the moment and I believe for a lot of other people too. A lot of the advice that's floating around the internet seems to be very misleading.

### What am I trying to do?

I am trying to build a basic web page with just plain TypeScript and HTML. I want to include the compiled JavaScript with a standard `<script>` tag such as

```
<script src="javascriptOutput/myCompiledJsFile.js></script>
```

while still being able to use normal module functionality of TypeScript, meaning splitting my code up into different files and importing them in the main script `myCompiledJsFile.js` that I include in my HTML.

### What's the problem?

With the following `tsconfig.json` ,

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs"
    // ...
  }
}
```

the JavaScript console always throws this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined`.

From what I have read it seems like the problem lies in the module system being specified as `commonjs`, which doesn't seem to work without an external module loader (like SystemJS, the one included in Webpack etc.).

I think it should be possible to use TypeScript without one of these external module loaders, if I am right. But I don't know how to configure TypeScript to compile in such a way that browsers can run the compiled code without the `Uncaught ReferenceError`. And I also don't know where you can find this information on what browsers support which module loaders / module systems. Do I have to look at the JavaScript engine the browser runs (e.g. V8 for Chrome) ?

I also don't want to work with any 'hacks' like adding `var scripts = {}` or the like or removing lines in the compiled JS.

Comment: So why commonjs?

Comment: What else though? That is my question. @ritaj

Comment: ES6 for example. Where are 9 options, your IDE should tell you about them with autocomplete. `Specify module code generation: 'None', 'CommonJS', 'AMD', 'System', 'UMD', 'ES6', 'ES2015', 'ES2020' or 'ESNext'. Only 'AMD' and 'System' can be used in conjunction with --outFile.`

Comment: @ritaj and I need to add the `type="module"` tag in my `<script>` when using ES6, right? And also, where do you get this information from which options the browsers support? Since it at least doesn't support `commonjs`

Comment: It depends on the browser. Every major browser understands ES6 modules. CommonJS is not supported in browsers at all, not without some kind of transpiling.

Comment: @ritaj and how do I find out which browsers support which module systems?

Comment: They support only those module systems of the javascript implementation they support. https://caniuse.com/#search=es6

Comment: @ritaj Okay, thanks. I also looked it up at http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ as well. So, the browsers don't support **any** module system except the native ES one, am I right?

Answer (score 4):

In case someone is wondering: the solution to my problem was to use the native ES module system. That means choosing either `ES2015` or `ES2020` for the `module` key in the `tsconfig.json`, based on what the browser supports. Since I was looking to run my code in Chrome only (Electron) and Chrome fully supports ES2020 as of today, I chose to use `ES2020` for my module system.

If you choose to use these modules, AFAIK, you need to add the `type="module"` attribute to your script tag:

```
<script src="../myJsFolder/myJs.js" type="module"></script>
```